# How to assign RGB color to a scatterplot in Octave?

Tags: octave, scatter-plot

According to [this](https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.1/Colors.html), RGB triplet colors with values from 0 to 1 can be specified in Octave.

How to do that for a scatter plot of two vectors of equal length, where all points will have the same RGB color `[0.5,0,0.5]`?

I tried the following:

```
a = randn(100,1);
b = randn(100,1);
scatter(a,b,[0.5,0,0.5],'filled')

error: __scatter__: mx_el_or: nonconformant ar
guments (op1 is 100x1, op2 is 3x1)
error: called from
    __scatter__ at line 52 column 7
    scatter at line 86 column 10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation on `scatter()`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/scatter.html) tells you that the syntax is `scatter(x,y,s,c)`, i.e. x-coordinate, y-coordinate, **size**, colour. Size is the 1D radius of a point and thus is either a scalar, setting all points to equal size, or an array as large as `x` and `y` to set each point to an individual size. The error you get is that you specified 3 size values to 100 points.

This also directly points to the solution: you forgot an argument.
Simply make all points the same size:

```
scatter(a,b,3,[0.5,0,0.5], 'filled')
```

This will give each point the size 3 and colour as specified by your RGB values.